# To find the $\phi(x)$ for particular value of x.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, integral-equations

> Let $\phi(x)$ be solution of   $$x=\int_{0}^{x}\exp(x-t)\phi(t)dt, \quad x\gt0.$$
>   Then $\phi(1)$ is given by
>
> 1. -1
> 2. 0
> 3. 1
> 4. 2

Now I know how to verify whether a function is solution of integral equation or not but here  I guess $\phi(x)=x$ gives $\phi(1)=1$.
Am I right? Please help me to find the correct option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}\exp(x-t)\phi(t)dt=\exp(x-x)\phi(x)+\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{d\exp(x-t)}{dx}\phi(t)dt$$

and differentiate the given equation with respect to $x$ to obtain:

$$1=\exp(x-x)\phi(x)+\int_{0}^{x}\exp(x-t)\phi(t)dt$$
$$1=\phi(x)+x\implies \phi(x)=1-x$$

Answer (score 3):

Use Laplace method and get $\dfrac{1}{s^2}=\dfrac{1}{s-1}{\cal L}(\phi)$. Then find $\phi$.

Comment: I don't think so. It just the solution. but thanks!